# Visualizing PCA with large number of variables in R using ggbiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggbiplot, biplot

I am trying to visualize a PCA that includes 87 variables.

```
prc <-prcomp(df[,1:87], center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)
ggbiplot(prc, labels = rownames(df[,1:87]), var.axes = TRUE)
```

When I create the biplot, many of the vectors overlap with each other, making it impossible to read the labels. I was wondering if there is any way to only show some of the labels at a time. For example, I think it'd be useful if I could create a few separate biplots with each one showing only a subset of the labels on the vectors.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35917067/r-visualizing-a-data-set-with-large-number-of-variables-using-pca-ggbiplot) seems closely related, but I don't know if it translates to the latest version of ggbiplot. I'm also not sure how to modify the original functions.

Answer (score 5):

A potential solution is to use the `factoextra` package to visualize your PCA results. The `fviz_pca_biplot()` function includes a `repel` argument. When `repel = TRUE` the plot labels are spread out to minimize overlap. There are also `select.var` options mentioned in the documentation, such as `select.var = list(contrib=5)` to display only the 5 most influential vectors. Also a `select.var = list(name)` option that seems to allow for the specification of a specific subset of variables that you want shown.

```
# read data
df <- mtcars[, c(1:7,10:11)]

# perform PCA
library("FactoMineR")
res.pca <- PCA(df, graph = FALSE)

# visualize
library(factoextra)
fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca, repel = TRUE, select.var = list(contrib = 5))
```

[image: biplot with only 5 vectors shown]